# How to have menu link highlighted on each page (section) in one page scroll master plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am currently developing a website which I am using a plugin called one page scroll master. The link is here: https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll/blob/master/README.md.

Everything is working well however I have a fixed header at the very top which has 4 menu links. What I would like is when you click the link for example 'about', it scrolls to the about page and the about link is highlighted. At the same time, When the user decides to scroll through the page, I would like the links highlighted depending on what page he is on for example if he scrolls to portfolio page, the portfolio link is highlighted.

So far I have done this however the links do not highlight when scrolling through the pages. It only highlights when you click on the actual link.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#home').css('color','white');

$("#home").on("click", function(){
 $(".main").moveTo(1);
   $("#contact").removeAttr("style");
  $("#about").removeAttr("style");
  $("#portfolio").removeAttr("style");
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){


$("#about").on("click", function(){
 $(".main").moveTo(2);
 $('#about').css('color','white');
  $("#contact").removeAttr("style");
  $("#home").removeAttr("style");
  $("#portfolio").removeAttr("style");
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#portfolio").on("click", function(){
 $(".main").moveTo(3);
 $('#portfolio').css('color','white');
  $("#about").removeAttr("style");
  $("#home").removeAttr("style");
  $("#contacct").removeAttr("style");
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#contact").on("click", function(){
 $(".main").moveTo(4);
 $('#contact').css('color','white');
  $("#about").removeAttr("style");
  $("#home").removeAttr("style");
  $("#portfolio").removeAttr("style");
});
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To tell you the truth, your code is something very different from what you want to do. I will answer your question with a new code, ok?

First of all, put this on each menu link you have:

```
data-target="#id"
```

Change id for your ids (#about, #port ...)

Ok. Now on the bottom of body tag you put your script tag and this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav li a').click(function() {

        $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = $(this).attr("data-target");

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 2000);

    });

});
```